# How to access the root app state in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have I loading indicator dialog in my main app component. I like to call `showLoadingDlg` from a sub component. I tried `_AppLayoutPageState state = _AppLayoutPageState .of(context);` but I'm able to import `_AppLayoutPageState` in my sub component.

```
class AppLayoutPage extends StatefulWidget {
  AppLayoutPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _AppLayoutPageState createState() => _AppLayoutPageState();
}

class _AppLayoutPageState extends State<AppLayoutPage> {

  bool _loading = false;

  showLoadingDlg() {
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
  }

  hideLoadingDlg() {
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the bloc pattern and share a stream between your components, You can listen for the stream in your root widget and then you can send some data through the stream from your child widget to show the dialog.